# Windows batch using variable content as another vatiable name

Tags: batch-file

I need to use one variable content which is in string format, as a name to other variable and call that variable content.

something like:

```
set upd1= c:\test1
set testval=upd1

set upd=%testval%

echo %upd%
```

result is upd1 and I would like to get result to show c:\test1

Comment: Looks like "set testval=%upd1%" to me and it feels too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set name=foo
set foo=bar
echo !%name%!
```

Echoes "bar".

Answer (score 2):

you should change

```
set testval=upd1
```

as `set testval=%upd1%`

Comment: with the command `set testval=%upd1%` the variable `testval` gets the content (= the _expanded_ variable) and **NOT** the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "upd1= c:\test1"
set "testval=upd1"
set "upd=testval"
ECHO %upd%
CALL ECHO %%%upd%%%
CALL CALL ECHO %%%%%%%upd%%%%%%%
```

---

output:

```
testval
upd1
 c:\test1
```

Comment: That would do the trick but what if I need to reuse the variable? Let’s say that I want to make a batch that would define a upd variable depending on the file name itself and do a specific action.
`set upd1=c:\upd`
`set upd2=d:\upd`
`set upd3=e:\upd`
`set fn=%~n0`
`REM this is the part that I can not get to work.. I want to pass file    name as a call to variable`
`set upd=%fn%` 
`for %%x in (exe ini) do xcopy /D /Y c:\test\*.%%x %upd%`
If the above code is executed by upd1.bat the xcopy should copy the content to c:\upd, and if it is executed by upd3.bat the content should be copied to e:\upd

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set upd1= c:\test1
set testval=upd1
::
:: First way - if value may not begin "="
::
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%i IN ('set %testval%') DO IF /i "%%i"=="%testval%" SET upd2=%%j


ECHO(first way+%upd2%+
ENDLOCAL
SETLOCAL
set upd1=x====== c:\test1
set testval=upd1
::
:: Second way - value may begin "="
::
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('set %testval%') DO ECHO %%i|FINDSTR /i /b /l /c:"%testval%=" >nul&IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET upd2=%%i
CALL SET upd2=%%upd2:*%testval%=%%
SET upd2=%upd2:~1%

ECHO(second way+%upd2%+
SET upd
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's two ways depending on your circumstances. Note I've changed the name `upd` to `upd2` for easy comparison using the final `set` command. Also that your original value of `upd1` contains a space; hence I've added a `+` to visually delimit the value `echo`ed.